# ghostscript fonts

Tags: linux, fonts, ghostscript, truetype

I'm trying to get ghostscript to render a pdf file from a Windows box.  The pdf file uses the ComicSansMS font.  I've copied the comic.ttf file from my Windows7 box into my /usr/share/ghostscript/fonts directory, and I've created a Fontmap file in that same directory containing this line:

```
/ComicSansMS (comic.ttf) ;
```

As nearly as I can tell, the font is not being found despite this.  The text comes out very poorly, and some of the smaller font sizes are rendered half the size they should be.  Access times and strace show that the Fontmap file is being read, but the font file (comic.ttf) is not being accessed at all.  There are no error messages:

```
hope 78$ gs cards-01.pdf
GPL Ghostscript  9.00 (2010-09-14)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
```

If I use -dFAPIDEBUG on the gs command line, I see the following:

```
hope 74$ gs -dFAPIDEBUG -I/usr/share/ghostscript/fonts cards-01.pdf
GPL Ghostscript  9.00 (2010-09-14)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
FAPIhook --nostringval--
Trying to render the font Font --nostringval-- ( aliased from ComicSansMS ) with FAPI...
Font --nostringval-- ( aliased from ComicSansMS ) is being rendered with FAPI=FreeType
FAPIhook --nostringval--
Font --nostringval-- ( aliased from ComicSansMS ) is mapped to FAPI=FreeType
FAPIhook RVJCAL+SymbolMT
Trying to render the font Font RVJCAL+SymbolMT with FAPI...
Font RVJCAL+SymbolMT is being rendered with FAPI=FreeType
FAPIhook RVJCAL+SymbolMT
Font RVJCAL+SymbolMT is mapped to FAPI=FreeType
FAPIhook HYLUQF+ComicSansMS
Trying to render the font Font HYLUQF+ComicSansMS with FAPI...
Font HYLUQF+ComicSansMS is being rendered with FAPI=FreeType
FAPIhook HYLUQF+ComicSansMS
Font HYLUQF+ComicSansMS is mapped to FAPI=FreeType
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
```

Naturally, the line from the above that most concerns me is this one:

```
Font --nostringval-- ( aliased from ComicSansMS ) is being rendered with FAPI=FreeType
```

"gs -h" shows that the font directory is, indeed, in the search path:

```
hope 77$ gs -h
GPL Ghostscript  9.00 (2010-09-14)
    [ ... ]
Search path:
   /usr/share/ghostscript/9.00/Resource/Init :
   /usr/share/ghostscript/9.00/lib :
   /usr/share/ghostscript/9.00/Resource/Font :
   /usr/share/ghostscript/fonts : /usr/share/fonts/Type1 : /usr/share/fonts
```

I've tried several permutations of formatting in the Fontmap file, including:

```
(Comic Sans MS) (comic.ttf) ;
(ComicSansMS) (comic.ttf) ;
/Comic Sans MS (comic.ttf) ;
/ComicSansMS /comic.ttf ;
```

I'm fairly sure my original one is the correct one, but I was getting desperate.  :-P

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a sample PDF? Is the ComicSansMS font embedded in the PDF (or why do you see the "funny" prefix to the fontname?)?

Comment: Well, hmm...  I'm not sure I can provide the file, as it's nearly a megabyte in size.  I assume the font isn't embedded, or it would work, right?

Comment: For now, though, I've somewhat given up.  I dug up an old copy of PhotoShop and wrote some Javascript to make PhotoShop do what I needed done.  It's ugly, but involved a lot less wrestling.  =/  I'd still love to see ghostscript do the job, since it seems like it should be able to, but it's more for my own education than anything else now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back to this problem after a delay.  Upon further investigation with a magnifying glass, the problem is different from what I initially thought.

Text is definitely being rendered incorrectly in parts of the document.  Each letter is far too small, though the spacing is oddly correct.  However, the individual letters are the correct shape for the font.

The font on disk is not being accessed, but that's because the fonts are all embedded within the document.  This fact would probably have been obvious to a Ghostscript expert from the output I posted in the original question (I'm guessing the "HYLUQF+" prefix is the smoking gun there), but I don't work with Ghostscript much.  My fonts were installed correctly, and other documents were able to access them without trouble.

Of course, this still leaves the question of why my embedded fonts are being rendered incorrectly, but I will investigate that separately and/or post a different question.  I maintain that the PDF file is uncorrupted (I have several other PDFs which exhibit the same problem), but I still don't know what's wrong.

@pipitas: Thanks very much for trying.  You certainly did help verify that my installed fonts are not the problem.  Actually, now that I look again, you even gently suggested the font might be embedded, but I either didn't see it, didn't believe it, or didn't know how to check.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that PDF does not have the ComicSansMS font embedded?

You should consider 2 other possibilities as well:

1. Your PDF file `card-01.pdf` is somehow corrupted. (Are other PDF viewers rendering that file without a problem? Does it display OK in Acrobat Reader on Widnows?)
2. Your fontfile `comic.ttf` is somehow corrupted. (Which method did you use to transfer it from Windows to Linux?)

You could try to positively proof that both these components are getting along well enough with each other by using Ghostscript+comic.ttf to **create** a PDF (with comic.ttf embedded):

```
gs \
  -sFONTPATH=/usr/share/ghostscript/fonts \
  -o comic-ttf.pdf \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -g5950x8420 \
  -c "200 700 moveto" \
  -c "/ComicSansMS findfont 60 scalefont setfont" \
  -c "(comic.ttf) show showpage"
```

On Windows, use this variation of above command:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
  -o comic-ttf.pdf ^
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
  -sFONTPATH=c:/windows/fonts ^
  -g5950x8420 ^
  -c "200 700 moveto" ^
  -c "/ComicSansMS findfont 60 scalefont setfont" ^
  -c "(comic.ttf) show showpage"
```

When I do this, I see:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
   -o comic-ttf.pdf ^
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
   -sFONTPATH=c:/windows/fonts ^
   -dHaveTrueTypes=true ^
   -g5950x8420 ^
   -c "200 700 moveto" ^
   -c "/ComicSansMS findfont 60 scalefont setfont" ^
   -c "(comic.ttf) show showpage"
GPL Ghostscript  9.00 (2010-09-14)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Scanning c:/windows/fonts for fonts... 423 files, 255 scanned, 240 new fonts.
Loading ComicSansMS font from c:/windows/fonts/comic.ttf... 3343720 1813337 2926116 1611207 1 done.
```

and my output PDF `comic-ttf.pdf` looks OK and does have the comic.ttf font embedded.

If this does also work for you, then your Ghostscript and your comic.ttf are OK, but your PDF file `cards-01.pdf` is not.

Comment: The PDF file is definitely fine.  I can read it without trouble in Acrobat Reader, both on Windows and Macintosh.  As for the comic.ttf file, I don't know whether it's corrupted, but I'm fairly sure it's irrelevent, since the file isn't being opened at all.  I made sure the filesystem was mounted with strictatime option, and the access time isn't being changed.  Also, I ran ghostscript under strace, and I can see the Fontmap file being opened, but ghostscript never accesses the font file.  I tried the command you suggested, and it does appear to work, outputting comic-ttf.pdf without error.

Comment: I suppose it's possible that my PDF isn't referencing the font I think it is.  I'm dubious about this possibility, given the messages I'm seeing from gs -dFAPIDEBUG (see original post), but I'm not a ghostscript expert.

Comment: @Rick Koshi: If your PDF doesn't have ComicSansMS embedded, your PDF viewer needs to use the one on the system. So it is ***NOT*** at all irrelevant if that one is corrupted or valid!

Comment: @Rick Koshi: ...so you now have positive proof that *comic.ttf* is valid, and that your Ghostscript 9.00 is able to handle that font as well! So most likely something's wrong with the PDF...

Comment: @Rick Koshi: you should be aware that Acrobat sometimes silently "repairs" PDF files which are damaged and displays them fine. However, other viewers/post-processors may have problems with such damaged PDFs nevertheless...

Comment: @Rick Koshi: you could do a few more cross-checks:  (a) Install Ghostscript 9.00 on Windows and check if the PDF works then.  (b) Try a few non-Ghostscript PDF consumers/viewers on Linux and check if these work with the PDF.

Comment: @Rick Koshi: Can you provide the output of this command: `pdffonts cards-01.pdf` ?  (pdffonts is part of the package `xpdf-utils` or `poppler-utils` on Linux. A `pdffonts.exe` is also available on Windows from http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html (as part of their `xpdf-****.zip` package).

Comment: @Rick Koshi: Your quoted commandline `gs -dFAPIDEBUG -I/-I/usr/share/ghostscript/fonts cards-01.pdf` above contains a typo: you have a doubled part `-I/-I` in it. The correct way would be `gs -dFAPIDEBUG -I/usr/share/ghostscript/fonts cards-01.pdf`

Comment: @Rick Koshi: To force Ghostscript's use of your Fontmap files you can add `-sFontmap=/path/to/first/Fontmap:/path/to/second/fontMAP.whatever`

Comment: @Rick Koshi: Note that Ghostscript tries to use the first font that it thinks does match the need. So make sure your paths are organized in a way that ensures usage of your real comic.ttf. See also this: http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.00/Use.htm#Font_lookup